# Symfony2: Change property of object in the session

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have a serialized object in the session.

When I want to change just one property of this object, is this really the only way to go:

```
$foo = $session->get('foo');
$foo->setBar('Hello');
$session->set('foo', $foo);
```

Isn't there a way to modify the property directly in the session, without having go fetch the entire object from the session?

Something like `$session->set('foo.bar','Hello');`

**EDIT:** I have read http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#attributes but (as I understand it) this applies only to arrays, not objects. In any case, `$session->set('foo/bar', 'hello');` doesn't work: It creates a new entry in session (sibling to `foo`), named `foo/bar`.

Comment: If i remember well PHP 5 doesn't return a object, but a reference, so if you do:
$session->get('foo')->setBar('Hello');
that will do the work.

I suggest to try that

Comment: @AndreaPosadino: Yeah, thanks , that's it! :-)

Comment: @AndreaPosadino: Please post this as an answer. Easy points for you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in a comment you can use this solution:

```
$session->get('foo')->setBar('Hello');
```

I hope this helps!